# jQuery prependTo a class descended from $(this)

Tags: jquery

How can I prepend to a class specifically descended from $(this) e.g. I only want to prepend to the div that's actually clicked in this example...

```
<div>
 <div class='target'></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div class='target'></div>
</div>



$('div').click(function(){
  $('<div>hello</div>').prependTo('.target');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only hook the relevant divs, then use `this` within the handler (but see also below, I can read your question two different ways):

```
$('div.target').click(function(){
  $('<div>hello</div>').prependTo(this);
});
```

Within an event handler hooked up via jQuery, `this` refers to the specific DOM element you hooked the handler to that received the event. See the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation for details.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/usigol) (You also had the `}` and `)` at the end reversed, causing a syntax error.)

If your goal is to have a click anywhere on the *outer* div prepend in front of the target div, it's more like this:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  // Look for "target" divs within this div
  var target = $(this).find("div.target");

  // Did we find any?
  if (target[0]) {
    // Yes, prepend to it/them
    $('<div>hello</div>').prependTo(target);

    // And stop the event
    return false;
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/usigol/2) There we're using `this` again, but this time we're using it to find out if the `div` the event has propagated to contains a `div` with the class "target". If so, we prepend your "hello" div and stop the event via `return false;` (you could use `event.stopPropagation();` instead).

Comment: Thanks very much, the second example you gave was what I was looking for - works great.

Comment: With the second example, if you have more divs than the ones in the example you will be adding a click event to all of them. It will work because the event fired on other divs will not match the find("div.target") but you will be adding unnecessary click events with the consequent waste of space and cycles

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can first select this and prepend to it, something like:

```
$('div.target').click(function(){
  $(this).prepend('<div>hello</div>');
});
```

Update: You have to add the click to the targets instead to all divs or you will have double events.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.target').click(function(){
  $('<div>hello</div>').prependTo($(this));
});
```

there is a mistake in closing brackets. you have given `)}` , it should be `})`

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8SrAW/